# Can you shorten logging headers when using python logging `%(funcName)s`?

Tags: python, logging, instrumentation

Sometimes I configure the python logging formatter using the `%(funcName)s`. But I don't like this when the function names are really long.

**Can you shorten logging headers when using python logging `%(funcName)s`? If yes, how?**

Can you say... limit the total number of characters to like 10 characters?

Comment: can you post some code you want improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%(...)s` items in the logging format string are % replacements, and you can limit the length of a string replacement by doing something like `%(funcName).10s`

e.g.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(funcName).10s %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
)

logger = logging.getLogger()

def short():
    logger.info("I'm only little!")

def really_really_really_really_long():
    logger.info("I'm really long")

short()
really_really_really_really_long()
```

gives

```
andy@batman[17:54:01]:~$ p tmp_x.py 
short I'm only little!
really_rea I'm really long
```

Comment: props for elegant solution (I did not think to use the "." of the string format... I've only ever used that string format feature when doing floating point `%f` string formatting). One addition: if you change `%.10s` to `%10.10s` then you get a constant size 10 when the function is too short (makes your logging headers constant length).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith That's handy to know. Have you been able to find some decent documentation on the full extent of what you can do with `%s`? I would really like to link to some documentation, but the pages I've found only mention that `%s` calls `str()` on the object, but not much about modifiers.

Comment: I believe [the official python docs you are looking for are here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec). (If you know c-style printf then usually the same applies but C is a different language so the syntax probably is not exactly the same (comparing the syntax is a discussion for another time).)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `logging.formatter` class to get the desired formatting like below.

This is just an example. you should modify it based on your requirement

```python
class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    in_console = False
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_width = 30
        self.datefmt = '%H:%M:%S'

    def format(self, record):
        s = []
        cmodule = record.module + ":" + str(record.lineno)
        cmodule = cmodule[-self.mod_width:].ljust(self.mod_width)
        format_str = ("%-7s %s %s" % (record.levelname, self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt), cmodule))
        pad_len = len(format_str)
        for line in record_msg[1:]:
            line =  " " * pad_len + " : " + line
            s.append(line)

        s = "%s : %s" % (format_str, "\n".join(s))
        return s

    my_formatter = MyFormatter()
    log.setFormatter(my_formatter)
```